# Instapy, getting a list of who a user is following with parameters

Tags: python, selenium, instapy

I'm getting a list of who a user's following in Instagram using Instapy. How do I create parameters so i only get users who have followers between 5k-10k alongside the grab_following function?

```
with smart_run(session):
    count = 1
    sessionCount = random.randint(accountsPerSessionMin, accountsPerSessionMax)

    print('======main.py====== Reading ' + str(sessionCount) + ' accounts')

    followersList.reverse()

    print('ji')

    for friend in followersList:
        followers = session.grab_following(
            username=friend, amount="full", live_match=True, store_locally=True)

        print(followers.get_relationship_counts())

        if (len(followers) > 0):
            # Write result
            with open('data/' + user + '-res/' + friend + '.txt', 'w') as outFile:
                outFile.write(json.dumps(followers))

        # Write to previously checked accounts
        alreadyDone.append(friend)
        with open('data/already-done.txt', 'w') as outFile:
            outFile.write(json.dumps(alreadyDone))

        count += 1
        print('======main.py====== Read account #' + str(count))

        if len(followers) > 0:
            print('======main.py====== Found ' +
                  str(len(followers)) + ' users')

        if count % sessionCount == 0:
            print('======main.py====== Finished!')
            exit(0)

        if count % 2 == 0:
            time.sleep(random.randint(6, 24))
            session.browser.get('https://instagram.com')
            time.sleep(random.randint(8, 12))
            for i in range(random.randint(1, 3)):
                session.browser.execute_script(
                    'window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
                time.sleep(random.randint(15, 45))
```